# PowerBi - Powerquery: If Folder/File we are loading from a path doesn't exist, change path

Tags: file, error-handling, path, powerbi, powerquery

I'm loading files from every client folder with a parameter. Some of the folders don't contain the files that are needed to load on powerquery. Because those files may or may not exist.

I tried to use: "try - otherwise" to change the path to a "standard folder" if the files are not found.

Is there any solution? or another way to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: You could count the number of files returned instead of handling it as an error

Comment: How? I don't understand

Comment: The problem is that the path doesn't exist or that the files are not in the path?

Comment: The files are not in the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query would define two sources, one the target and one the default. If the target doesn't return any files, then it'd load the default.

```
let
    DefaultSource = Folder.Files("C:\DefaultPath"),
    TargetSource = Folder.Files("C:\TargetPath"),
    FileCounter = Table.RowCount(Source),
    DoSomething = if FileCounter > 0 then TargetSource else DefaultSource
in
    DoSomething
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: What should I put in "Source"? -- FileCounter = Table.RowCount(Source)

Comment: You can use the advance editor and paste the code. From there you can adjust it

Comment: Yes I did. I mean, I have a problem with this line "FileCounter = Table.RowCount(Source)", it says:  Expression.Error: The name 'Source' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: Try to paste the whole in a new query

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ricardo Diaz answer as a start (thank you Ricardo!), I made it work:

1. Create Blank Query
2. Code:

```
= let
    Path1 = "D:\OneDrive\",
    Path2 = "C:\Users\OneDrive\",
    DefaultSource = Folder.Files(Path1),
    AlternateSource = Folder.Files(Path2),
    FileCounter1 =   try Table.RowCount(DefaultSource) otherwise 0,
    FileCounter2 =   try Table.RowCount(AlternateSource) otherwise 0,
    WorkingPath = if FileCounter1 > FileCounter2 then Path1 else Path2
in
    WorkingPath
```

3. Then you can call this Query.

I hope it helps